# iOS tag friend in status update

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-timeline

I'm currently using iOS Facebook SDK 3.1.  To post a feed story to a users timeline, when on < iOS 6, i've been using `+[FBRequest requestForPostStatusUpdate:place:tags:]`.  This works great, except when I attept to tag a friend [such as I would when typing `@FRIENDS_NAME` on Facebook.com into the composer.  I know that I can pass an array of objects to the `tags:` argument, however, as I expected, also passing nil to `place` yields an error **(#100) Cannot specify user tags without a place tag**.

For sake of completion, here's an example of what I was using:

```
NSArray *tags = @[@(FB_UID)];

[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:@"Friends Name, this is a test"
                                        place:nil
                                         tags:tags
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                            }];
```

Now I understand that using this method, it's not possible to tag a friend in my status. However, is there a method, any method, using the graph API to tag a friend in a feed post, the same way it'd work tagging a user on Facebook.com?  I've spent the better part of this morning looking for answers, and i've yet to find any solutions. Any questions i've found on it seem to be at least a year old, so I wasn't sure if they were still relevant anyway.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, is there a method, any method, using the graph API to tag a friend in a feed post, the same way it'd work tagging a user on Facebook.com?

No.

> I've spent the better part of this morning looking for answers, and i've yet to find any solutions.

That’s because there are none – Facebook deactivated this feature for posts made via API quite a while ago.

---

For Open Graph actions, the situation is different – the allow something called [mention tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/).

Comment: OK, thank you very much.  I didn't think it were possible, but getting an up-to-date answer is the definitive nail in the coffin.  I'll look into using Open Graph actions.